# opencv connect thin lines

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a black and white image with lines. some of these lines, however, are not perfectly connected where they should be (though they are close) I have attached an example. [image: open]

I want to make it so that the lines are close to 1px thick. I have been playing with a few ideas, but not having much sucess. I have tried dilate erote, and dilate like such:

```
int dsize = 5;
cv::Mat element = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS,
                          cv::Size(2*dsize + 1, 2*dsize + 1),
                          cv::Point( dsize, dsize ) );
cv::dilate( src, src, element );
```

Is there a better way, as op[p[osed to just dilating and eroding to do specifically what I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least a couple of solutions we can try out, but I'm gonna need more info about your problem. For example, are you trying to close the (in)complete contour of a detected object? How much "contour degradation" are you willing to take to approximate a fully closed contour?

Here's a first and very basic solution, assuming you need a `1 pixel` width contour. It involves `dilating` the image `N` times and then applying a `thinning/skeletonize` transformation. (The function is part of the `Extended Image Processing` module of OpenCV ).

Let's see the code:

```
#include <opencv2/ximgproc.hpp>

//Read input image:
std::string imagePath = "C://opencvImages//lineImg.png";
cv::Mat imageInput= cv::imread( imagePath );

//Convert it to grayscale:
cv::Mat grayImg;
cv::cvtColor( imageInput, grayImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

//Get binary image via Otsu:
cv::threshold( grayImg, grayImg, 0, 255 , cv::THRESH_OTSU );

//Dilate the binary image with 5 iterations:
cv::Mat morphKernel = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3) );
int morphIterations = 5;
cv::morphologyEx( grayImg, grayImg, cv::MORPH_DILATE, morphKernel, cv::Point(-1,-1), morphIterations );
```

This is the Dilated image:

[image]

```
//Get the skeleton:
cv::Mat skel;
int algorithmType = 1;
cv::ximgproc::thinning( grayImg, skel, algorithmType );
```

This is the *Skeleton Image*. The line has been "thinned" back to a width of 1 pixel:

[image]

I don't know if this is good enough for your application, but, as I said, depending on what you are doing we can try a couple of alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it you who draw the lines to the mat, It seems like the problem should be take in hands before. 
You should draw line in a bigger cv::mat then resize to make your line thicker.
if you want to have complete line, don't draw each points on the map but line between points to get line from bresenham.

Comment: Ah, I just want to have a complete line, Dilating and eroding has just been my attempt as solving the problem. If you have a better way of completing the line I would prefer that one.

Comment: do the white pixel have a thickness superior than 1 pixel ?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Each square in that image is 1 pixel, and that is an example on one of my lines.

Comment: ok so you have a broken non linear line and you would like to make it smoothier, for example transform the sample in a smooth curved line